# Converting bbcode into special format

Tags: java, bbcode

I'm trying to parse BBCode, specifically, XenForo's BBCode into strings, however, replacing with specific characters.

For example, here's a quote and a response.

```
"[QUOTE=\"admin, post: 775, member: 1\"]\nThis is a post that is being quoted.\n[/QUOTE]\nThis is awesome! Responding to your post!\n\n"
```

I'd like to convert this into this specific string.

```
&oThis is a post that is being quoted.&r
&fThis is awesome! Responding to your post!&r &7-admin
```

This is Minecraft color code formatting. The `&o` would italicize the quote and the &r would be at the end to reset the formatting.

Same thing goes for bold!

```
[b]This is bolded text[/b]
```

Change into

```
&lThis is bolded text&r
```

How can I do this with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to string format and use String replace() in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "[b]This is bolded text[/b]";  
    String replaceString = s1.replace("[b]", "&l");
    replaceString = replaceString.replace("[/b]", "&r");
    System.out.println(replaceString);  
}
```